# Using system variable in Spring Boot's application.properties

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot

I have this property in my application.property file

```
logfile.dir=/Users/Nunito/logs/bonanza/
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like:

```
logfile.dir=/Users/{userName}/logs/bonanza/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can read environment variables from properties file. Provided **username** is configured as environment variable in the system you want to execute the code on.

simply replace,

**this:** logfile.dir=/Users/Nunito/logs/icrypts/

**with:** logfile.dir=/Users/${userName}/logs/icrypts/

You can also read properties file using any of below ways.

```
@Value("${username}")
private String username;
```

You can also use, **SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON**

At application startup, Spring Boot will look for an environment variable called SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON. It can be used to provide a set of application properties using inline JSON. For example, you can set ec2.public.url property as follows.

You can refer samples from here,
https://github.com/indrekots/spring-boot-envvariables

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Just use `${userName}`.